# Python Pandas: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'Timedelta'

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, timedelta, python-datetime

I want to sum two pandas Series.
The first series is a hh:mm time value; the second series contains Timedelta objects obtained from `pd.Timedelta`.

The expected result is a hh:mm time regardless of day change (e.g. 22:00 + 4 hours = 02:00).

I created the Delta series like this:

```
delta = pd.Series(0 for x in range(0, len(df.Time_In_Hours)))

for j in range(0, len(df.Time_In_Hours)):
    delta[j] = pd.Timedelta(df.Time_In_Hours[j], 'h')
df = df.assign(Delta = delta)   
print ("Delta dtype = %s" % (df.Delta.dtype))
print ("Start_Time dtype = %s" % (df.Start_Time.dtype))

#Output
Delta dtype = object
Start_Time dtype = object
```

What I tried:

```
df["end_Time"] = df["Start_Time"] + df["Delta"]
```

The error I am receiving is:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'Timedelta'`

How can I sum these two series ?

Comment: Convert `df["Delta"]` to `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: related: [Python type error when adding TimedeltaIndex to date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70337502/10197418)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### The cause

The error is pretty clear. If you check the types of the elements, you will find out that at some point you are tying to add `datetime.time` object and `pandas.Timedelta`.

There are 2 kinds of dates, times and timedeltas:

- python's builtin from `datetime` module i.e. `datetime.time`, `datetime.date`, `datetime.timedelta`, ...
- pandas / numpy i.e `pandas.Timestamp`, `pandas.Timedelta`

these two stacks are incompatible for basic operations as addition or comparison.

#### Solution 1

Convert everything to pandas type and extract the times in the end

You should make sure, that `dtypes` of your columns are something like `datetime64[ns]` and `timedelta64[ns]`. For that, try converting them explicitly using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_timedelta`.

#### Solution 2

Another approach would be just converting the `Delta` column to `datetime.timedelta` you could try

```
df["end_Time"] = df["Start_Time"] + df["Delta"].map(pd.Timedelta.to_pytimedelta)
```

But you may run into some more errors depending on what is in your `df["Delta"]` and `df["Start_Time"]`

Comment: pd.to_timedelta worked well for the Delta series to turn it into timedelta64[ns] format but I was having no success converting the Start_Time series into datetime64[ns] with pd.to_datetime.  Another poster suggested converting to string and then using pd.to_datetime which did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import datetime as dt

df["end_Time"] = df["Start_Time"] + df["Delta"].map(dt.timedelta)
```