# Substracting a date from a pandas dataframe column in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following datetime date value:

```
a_date = datetime.date(2018,9,13)
```

And a pandas dataframe `df` with the following column:

```
df['somedates']

0      2010-07-27
1      1999-02-15
2      1997-07-15
3      2012-11-15
4      1999-02-17
5      1999-02-16
6      1999-02-17
7      2012-10-12
8      1999-09-22
9      1998-05-09
10     1998-05-09

Name: somedates, Length: 11, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I can do the following on my Windows machine and it works fine

```
df['somedates'] = a_date - df['somedates']
```

However on ubuntu it raises the following error:

`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date`

Can someone point me in the right the direction on this ? Why is it running on windows but not in Linux ?

**More detailed info**

```
print(type(a_date))
<class 'datetime.date'>

print(type(df['somedates']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

print(type(df['somedates'][0]))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Comment: Sounds more like a pandas / Python version issue...

Comment: @xyzjayne I doubled checked that and it's not...

Comment: I can replicate the error with my Windows machine, so it's possibly unrelated to the OS you're using...

Comment: what do you do to replicate that error on windows ? if you could share that would be of great help

Comment: Python versions are 3.6 and pandas 0.22 for me on both OS.

Comment: Python from command window and Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can't comment:

The reason why this wont work is because you are attempting to use the datetimes version of datetime with pythons version of datetime, [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506680/python-pandas-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and?rq=1). What I would do in your situation is convert everything to the same datetime with pd.to_datetime():

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

a_date = datetime.date(2018,9,13) # we can change this to a_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-9-13')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['somedates'] = ['2010-07-27', '1999-02-15', '1997-07-15','2012-11-15','2012-11-15','1999-02-17']

df['somedates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['somedates'])
df['somedates'] = pd.to_datetime(a_date) - df['somedates'] # if we enact the change above then we can simply do a_date - df['somedates']

display(df)
    somedates
0   2970 days
1   7150 days
2   7730 days
3   2128 days
4   2128 days
5   7148 days
```

I would also take a look at [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html)

Comment: Would you happen to know why was it working for me on my Windows machine even without casting `a_date` to `pd.to_datetime()` ?

Comment: @AnarKi sorry for the late response but sadly I do not =/