# How to manipulate index column by adding one month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a df:

```
date                open    high    low     close
12/31/2005 17:00    0.85224 0.88269 0.85    0.86321
1/31/2006  17:00    0.86321 0.86438 0.83967 0.84373
2/28/2006  17:00    0.84373 0.85519 0.82036 0.83613
3/31/2006  17:00    0.83655 0.85165 0.83237 0.84776
4/30/2006  17:00    0.84776 0.86062 0.82694 0.82836
5/31/2006  17:00    0.82836 0.83802 0.8121  0.8293
6/30/2006  17:00    0.8293  0.86851 0.82221 0.86665
7/31/2006  17:00    0.86665 0.86773 0.83658 0.84212
8/31/2006  17:00    0.84246 0.85794 0.82869 0.83334
9/30/2006  17:00    0.82987 0.86971 0.82661 0.86758
10/31/2006 17:00    0.86717 0.90246 0.86284 0.89894
11/30/2006 17:00    0.89853 0.9206  0.89402 0.91748
12/31/2006 17:00    0.91748 0.93901 0.90711 0.91386
1/31/2007  17:00    0.91346 0.92743 0.90495 0.921
2/28/2007  17:00    0.92083 0.94434 0.90589 0.93246
3/31/2007  17:00    0.93192 0.95089 0.91939 0.92037
4/30/2007  17:00    0.92024 0.92818 0.87458 0.88427
5/31/2007  17:00    0.88422 0.91127 0.87847 0.90419
6/30/2007  17:00    0.90183 0.92689 0.89691 0.90782
```

My index column is `dtype='datetime64[ns]`.

I try to manipuate `+1 month` by `df.index = df.index + relativedelta(months=+1)` and didn't work, got this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'relativedelta'`

Tried `df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index)` and didn't work `TypeError: dtype datetime64[ns] cannot be converted to timedelta64[ns]`
Checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506680/python-pandas-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and) already, but still have no idea how to do it. What can I do to add 1 month? Thanks.

**P.S. I want the dates to be the same, I don't think relativedelta can do that by the way, 3/31 will become 3/28 for instance...**

Comment: @MrFuppes - It seems OP need something else, check deleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you almost had it. Just had to add the `.date` to convert it to a date object so that its compatible for operations with `relativedelta`

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).date
df.index = df.index +  relativedelta(months=+1)
```

Input:

```
            date     open     high      low    close
12/31/2005  17:00  0.85224  0.88269  0.85000  0.86321
1/31/2006   17:00  0.86321  0.86438  0.83967  0.84373
2/28/2006   17:00  0.84373  0.85519  0.82036  0.83613
3/31/2006   17:00  0.83655  0.85165  0.83237  0.84776
4/30/2006   17:00  0.84776  0.86062  0.82694  0.82836
```

Output after running the code:

```
            date     open     high      low    close
2006-01-31  17:00  0.85224  0.88269  0.85000  0.86321
2006-02-28  17:00  0.86321  0.86438  0.83967  0.84373
2006-03-28  17:00  0.84373  0.85519  0.82036  0.83613
2006-04-30  17:00  0.83655  0.85165  0.83237  0.84776
2006-05-30  17:00  0.84776  0.86062  0.82694  0.82836
```

Comment: sorry, the new dates are different. 3/31 becomes 3/28 for instance.

Comment: Ah.. so you have a new problem now:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column to `datetime` type using:

```
df['date_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
```

and then apply the `relativedelta` function.