# How to add 8 months to a column in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a column "CropYear" in a dataframe that I want to add 8 months to (that is, 8 months to each datetime value in that column). I then would like to subtract that column from the Column "DateListed". I can accomplish either one of these things on my own, but can't for the life of me figure out how to do both at the same time without breaking my code.

```
df2["CropYear"] = pd.to_datetime(df2['CropYear'], format="%Y",  errors='coerce')

eight_mon_rel = relativedelta(months=8)

df2["CropYear"] = df2["CropYear"] + eight_mon_rel

HA = df2.DateListed - df2.CropYear
```

Here is a screenshot of the dataframe for reference:
[df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzoWB.png)

As it currently stands, my result from this code is

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'relativedelta'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'Timedelta'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506680/python-pandas-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and). Specifically, you're trying to add a `pandas.datetime` to a non-pandas `relativedelta`.

Comment: `pd.Timedelta(days=243) + pd.to_datetime(['2021-06-24'])`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new and apologize if I misinterpreted your question, but this might be what you're trying to do?

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset

#reading in your example data
original_data = pd.read_excel('Data_Example_Original.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

working_df = DataFrame(original_data)

add_time = list(working_df['CropYear'] + DateOffset(months=8))

working_df['AdjCropYear'] = add_time
working_df['DaysBetween'] = (working_df['DateListed'] - working_df['AdjCropYear']).dt.days
working_df.to_excel('results.xlsx')
```