# Python type error when adding TimedeltaIndex to date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I'm using Python 3.7.12 and trying to understand the behaviour of adding a `pandas.TimedeltaIndex` object to a `datetime.date` object, and specifically why I sometimes get a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TimedeltaArray' and 'datetime.date'` error. I am pulling data from a source and loading it into a dataframe with one or more rows, and attempting to add a new column to all rows containing the sum of the `datetime.date` and `pandas.TimedeltaIndex` for that row. My code works whenever there are at least two rows in the dataframe, e.g.

```py
import pandas as pd
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

data = {'dates': [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-27 15:59:59', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
                  pd.to_datetime('2017-04-28 15:59:59', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')],
        'deltas': ['90', '180']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['adjusted_dates'] = df['dates'].dt.date + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['deltas'].astype('int64'), unit='D')

# The deltas have been applied and df is in the expected shape
logging.debug("Job done")
```

If I have exactly one row in my data frame, however, I get the error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

data = {'dates': [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-27 15:59:59', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')],
        'deltas': ['90']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'TimedeltaArray' and 'datetime.date'
df['adjusted_dates'] = df['dates'].dt.date + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['deltas'].astype('int64'), unit='D')

# We don't get this far
logging.debug("Job done")
```

Why am I seeing this error for single-row data frames? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I found another question here on Stack Overflow that answers why my code would sometimes fail: [Python Pandas: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'Timedelta'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506680/python-pandas-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and)

I was attempting to add a Pandas `delta` object to a Python `datetime`, but these two stacks are incompatible. When I have Pandas objects for both operands, the dataframe is updated as expected for single-row as well as multi-row dataframes.

```py
df['adjusted_dates'] = df['dates'] + pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['deltas'].astype('int64'), unit='D')
```

Now that I see why my code didn't always succeed, I'm confused as to why it didn't always fail?

Comment: So, *I see why my code didn't always succeed, I'm confused as to why it didn't always fail* - what specifically still fails unexpectedly?

Comment: The *message* here is I think, if you do time series analysis in pandas, use [pandas timeseries functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html). ***Do not*** mix in Python datetime, date or time class objects. That will either fail or cripple the functionality you have at hand with pandas datetime (see e.g. [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#dt-accessor)).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify to

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['2017-04-27 15:59:59', '2017-04-28 15:59:59'],
                   'deltas': ['90', '180']})

# no need to provide a format, no need to use an index:
df['adjusted_dates'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['dates']) + 
                        pd.to_timedelta(df['deltas'].astype(int), unit='D'))

# df['adjusted_dates']
# 0   2017-07-26 15:59:59
# 1   2017-10-25 15:59:59
# Name: adjusted_dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or, if you just want to add the timedelta to the *date*, ignoring the time:

```py
df['adjusted_dates'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['dates']).dt.floor('D') + 
                        pd.to_timedelta(df['deltas'].astype(int), unit='D'))

# df['adjusted_dates']
# 0   2017-07-26
# 1   2017-10-25
# Name: adjusted_dates, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that in both cases, you'll have `datetime64[ns]` datatype. If you floor to the day, the time is *just not displayed* (defaults to zero / 00:00:00).